# Can't put Caml Query to wok properly

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I have a List called "WorkshopResults" that have a reference, Lookup Field "Participant" for a list called "Participant", so I want to get the "FirstName" from "Participant" List.

What I'm missing?

Thanks for help

```
"<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Id\" /><FieldRef Name=\"FirstName\" />
    </ViewFields>
    <Joins>
        <Join Type=\"LEFT\" ListAlias=\"Participant\"><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Participant\" RefType=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" List=\"Participant\" /></Eq></Join>
    </Joins>
    <ProjectedFields><Field ShowField=\"FirstName\" Type=\"Lookup\" Name=\"Participant\" List=\"Participant\" /></ProjectedFields>
    <Query><Where /></Query>
</View>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The migration of the site collection broke the lookup fields

Thanks